# Output of one command is piped to another one; how to close both?

Tags: pipe, kill, netcat

I call Qt Assistant like suggested on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843442/qt-5-open-documentation-for-particular-class-from-command-line):

```
nc -lkU ~/.assistantfifo | assistant -enableRemoteControl &
```

Qt Assistant window is opened, and if I call `jobs`, it returns:

```
[1]  + running    nc -lkU ~/.assistantfifo | assistant -enableRemoteControl
```

Then, I close Qt Assistant (just by clicking at "x"). Now, `jobs` returns:

```
[1]  + running    nc -lkU ~/.assistantfifo | 
       done       assistant -enableRemoteControl
```

So, `nc` continues working, and I have to type `killall nc`.

How to make `nc` finish too, when I close Qt Assistant? Or, probably I should do this somehow different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are running (`nc` a.k.a. `netcat`) will listen for input when run with the `-l` flag. Normally, netcat in listen mode will close when it receives the end-of-file character, but the `-k` flag prevents that. In other words, netcat won't close until you kill it because of the way you invoked the command.

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detach the 2nd process, you need also to group them with

```
$ ( nc -lkU ~/.assistantfifo | assistant -enableRemoteControl ) &
```

otherwise it wont work. The braces are needed to detach both processes.